# Jsoneditoutput is not displayed when given as reactive value in a shiny app

Tags: r, json, shiny

I have a `shiny` app which takes a csv file as input and after clicking 'submit' should display a `jsoneditOutput`. Besides this I have used a reset button which when clicked should reset the file input. But when I click submit I get:  `Error in read.table: 'file' must be a character string or connection`.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(tidyverse)
library(listviewer)
library(jsonlite)
library(SACCR)
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
  useShinyjs(),
  fileInput('inFile', 'Choose 1st file'),
  actionButton('submit', 'Submit'),
  tags$hr(),
  actionButton('reset', 'Reset')
    ),
  mainPanel(
    jsoneditOutput("choose")
  )
)
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  rv <- reactiveValues(
    data = NULL,
    clear = FALSE
  )

  ########1st
  observe({
    req(input$inFile)
    req(!rv$clear)

      rv$data <- read.csv(input$inFile$datapath,header = T)



  })

  observeEvent(input$inFile, {
    rv$clear <- FALSE
  }, priority = 1000)

  observeEvent(input$reset, {
    rv$data <- NULL
    rv$clear <- TRUE
    reset('inFile')
  }, priority = 1000)



  output$choose <- renderJsonedit({input$submit
    jsonedit(jsonlite::fromJSON(SACCR::SACCRCalculator(isolate(rv$data), JSON=TRUE)))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue is with this line:

`jsonedit(jsonlite::fromJSON(SACCR::SACCRCalculator(isolate(rv$data), JSON=TRUE)))`


The `SACCRCalculator` function needs a .csv file, not an R dataframe. Try replacing `rv$data` with `input$inFile$datapath`.


Also, the `SACCRCalculator` function requires three files in total; the trades, CSA, and collaterals. So that line will need to be expanded to include all three files. It should end up looking something like:
`SACCRCalculator(input$trades$datapath, input$csa$datapath, input$collaterals$datapath, JSON=TRUE)`

Comment: I followed your advice but submit button seems not to work for me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61355743/isolate-is-not-working-when-used-inside-an-if-statement-in-a-shiny-app